# namespace an attribute in an element inside of an xml file

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I wonder if its possible to add a namespace to an attribute inside an element.
This is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://fooschema.com"
        xmlns="http://fooschema.com"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        version="1.0">    

    <xs:element name = "class">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="student" type="StudentType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name = "StudentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = "firstname" type = "xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name = "rollno" type = "xs:positiveInteger"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And this my example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:class xmlns:xs = "http://fooschema.com">
    <xs:student rollno="393">
        <xs:firstname>Dinkar</xs:firstname>
    </xs:student>
</xs:class>
```

Now is there a way to add the `xs` namespace declaration to the `rollno` attribute like so:

```
<xs:student xs:rollno="393">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add:

```
attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
```

as part of the XSD definition.